# Replace all instances of YouTube / Vimeo iframe in string

Tags: javascript, regex, iframe, youtube

I have a string that might contain one or more instances of a YouTube or Vimeo iframe. I am looking for a javascript function that searches through this string, detects the ID of the video in the iframe src, then replaces the existing instances of the iframe with an iframe wrapped in a div.

So input would be:

```
<p>Interesting text, great, fantastic.</p>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/EShfC-uhlv8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<p>Another great thing</p>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/umiN04tPpl0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Output:

```
<p>Interesting text, great, fantastic.</p>
<div class="iframe-container">
  <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/EShfC-uhlv8?html5=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<p>Another great thing</p>
<div class="iframe-container">
  <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/umiN04tPpl0?html5=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

I have tried wrapping my brain around regexp, even with all the examples around I just can't seem to figure out how to do this.

Anyone have a solution?

Comment: What platform are you developing in? I've done this before by detecting the element in Javascript and just accessing it's bits, but I don't know if it would be helpful to you.

Comment: Just plain vanilla js. I can't use jQuery for this.

Comment: In that case I can help. I will post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Copy/pasting the work I am about to reference directly would get me in trouble, so hopefully an explanation of the methodology would be sufficient. ( If it's not, let me know. )

Assuming you have no idea of the names of the iframes, just plop down a [`getElementsByTagName(iframe)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName) and then iterate over the resulting array with a loop that gathers all the info from the iframe, which you will use to create a replacement element using [`innerHTML`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp). This replacement element will have you funky iframe wrapped in whatever you want. Finally, we use [`replaceChild(replacement, original)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.replaceChild) and you're set.

For example, here is how I create my replacement element:

```
var replacement = document.createElement("replacement");
replacement.innerHTML = 
"<div class=iframe-container>" 
    + "<iframe src=https://www.youtube.com/embed/EShfC-uhlv8?html5=1 frameborder=0 allowfullscreen></iframe>"
+ "</div>"
```

In simpler terms -- write the code as it would look in the .html file.

Another tricky thing you can do is adding IDs to all the elements and just going through them with [`getElementById`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp), but it seems like a lot of extra work, unless you're the one developing the page and can just ID-entify the iframes.

Let me know how it goes! If anything is unclear, which would be understandable, considering the format I've written all of this in, just let me know and I will help.

PS: I know a lot of people here don't like `innerHTML`. They are all pansies.